# Azure AD Bearer Token for integration tests?

Tags: azure, integration-testing, azure-active-directory, adal

We are about to start integration testing our REST API's, those are secured using ADAL.js / Bearer token / passport-azure-ad.

So now to the actual question, in an automated test, how would I go about to get a bearer token to pass to the API?

The test cannot open the browser and force a login using the login page so how would I go about getting the token via e.g. a Node.js script running the tests suite?

I cannot provide much more info because I do not know where to even start looking for this.

Answer (score 0):

You should start reading about [Service Principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-application-objects) since you want to get an access token for an application, not a user (principal). Basically instead of a username and passwort you will have a client id and client secret to retrieve an access token.

Certainly you have to create the service principal and grant it access to your application first.